# XmlUnit: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: java, unit-testing, xmlunit

I need to test a XHTML code like `<div>&nbsp;</div>` using XmlUnit. The Diff constructor tells me this:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but
>   not declared.

I know that *nbsp* entity is not defined in XML, but the HTML code is not mine, so I cannot replace it by *#160* (that would be obvious solution otherwise).

I don't want to modify the HTML code by adding `<!DOCTYPE html [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>`, I would prefer to leave the code without change.

Is there another way around this problem? I know there is a `HTMLDocumentBuilder` class in XmlUnit, but I wasn't able to find good documentation or examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOCTYPE declaration that refers to the [MathML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/appendixa.html#parsing.usingdtd):

```
<!DOCTYPE math 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd">
```

or a local copy of the same.

Comment: If I wanted to add DTD, wouldn't it be better to add directly XHTML DTD?
I believe this might be a solution, but I would prefer to leave source XHTML code without change (because your solution would raise some new issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error" to not throw an exception in case of unknown entities. This still gives a warning though:

```
documentBuilderFactory.setFeature(
            "http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error",
             true);
```

É voilá!